# Export only one value from a one-band raster

Tags: postgis, postgresql, export, geotiff-tiff, database

I have a PostGIS database with a georeferenced raster, with one band which contains values from 0 to 255.
I should export it to a transparent GeoTiff picture in which the only visible pixels are those of value 100.
How can I do this?